# wshShell.Exec Error 80070002 "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: shell, vbscript, exec, wsh

I'm trying to use either wshShell.Exec or wshShell.Run to run a script through another script. I have tried both methods, and both methods give me the same error. I've Googled the issue and can't find anything that seems to fix the issue. The only suggestion that really was very relevant was to try using wshShell.Run instead of Exec.

Here's the relevant part of my script:

```vbs
strScriptPath = "T:\IT resources\Scripts\Shutdown Scripts"
strForceShutdown = "ForceShutdown.vbs"

  For j = 0 to 99
   Set objActive = wshShell.Run(strForceShutdown)
   ' In case I ever need to get this working to run it from another folder. 
   ' Set objActive = wshShell.Exec("cd " & strScriptPath & "")
   ' Set objActive = wshShell.Exec("wscript " & strForceShutdown & "") 
    constConf = MsgBox("Automatic shutdown initializing. Continue?" & chr(10) & "Y=Shutdown N=Postpone 30 minutes",4,"Automatic Shutdown Notification")

     If constConf = 7 Then
      objActive.Terminate
      Wscript.Sleep(1800000)

      Else
       objActive.Terminate
       Exit For
     End If
   Next
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Shell.Run` [returns an integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), so you can't call a method (`Terminate`) on its return value. You also can't `Set` it since it's not an object.

You can call your shutdown script by just running it. Give it the full path, however, not a relative path. Scripts launched from Task Scheduler often have different "starting folders" than those launched manually so don't rely on your script finding the other one relatively.
Also, you'll have to add `Chr(34)` before and after your path to account for any spaces.

```
strForceShutdown = "c:\path\to\ForceShutdown.vbs"
wshShell.Run Chr(34) & strForceShutdown & Chr(34)
```

Finally, why launch the script *and then ask* whether to shutdown? Why not just launch your script after the user has responded and then you don't have to worry about terminating a running process.

Comment: Yep. Looks like I just read something wrong and thought it returned an object. Anyway, I'm running it this way so that I can get the computer to shutdown if no option has been selected after 30 minutes. Otherwise, if no one is at the computer, it will get stuck on the MsgBox line. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually, I needed the process to be terminateable. It looks like the only way to do that is with the Exec method. I got it working by adding "CMD" to the commands. The Terminate method only works with an object set by Exec. So it seems like Exec does return an object? Because it is working when I treat it as such. And I have seen it suggested elsewhere, after looking for some info on Terminate. Anyway, my script is working now with Exec, at least.

Comment: You can have a message box that disappears and performs a default action. See the [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method of the `Shell` class. If it returns -1, it means the timer elapsed.

Comment: So if the user clicks Yes to shutdown or if the Popup times-out after 30 minutes, use `Shell.Run` to launch your shutdown script. `If intResult = vbYes Or intResult = -1 Then wshShell.Run ...`

Comment: That would definitely help simplify my script a bit. Thanks for the info!